# npm ERR! when starting Angular Frontend App

Tags: javascript, angular, npm

[image]

```
> ng serve

sh: ng: command not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! syscall spawn

npm ERR! file sh

npm ERR! errno ENOENT

npm ERR! frontend@0.0.0 start: `ng serve`

npm ERR! spawn ENOENT

npm ERR! 

npm ERR! Failed at the frontend@0.0.0 start script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional
 logging output above.

npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/.npm/_logs/2021-08-09T13_47_00_579Z-debug.log

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: you've got a message that says that you miss `node_modules` did you try to run `npm install`? Read more about npm [here](https://nodesource.com/blog/an-absolute-beginners-guide-to-using-npm/)

Answer (score 0):

It says that it cannot find command `ng`. Did you run `npm install -g @angular/cli`?

If you are running multiple terminal windows, you might need to restart the one running ng if you installed it in another one.